# Is there an Alternative for AsyncTask using HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, android

Using AsyncTask freezes my whole app. i have an icon that rotates while the Http action is happening in the background. but the app just freezes till it finishes that action. Is there an alternative?

The below class sends the JSON to the server, the server has multiple endpoints and stuff like that. now when calling class calls the `execute()` method, the app freezes until the task is complete.

```
public class Connector extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

private String ip = "http://192.168.1.127";
private String port = "5000";

private URL Url;

private JSONObject jsonObject;
private String method = "";

private StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

Connector(String url, JSONObject jsonObject, String method)
{
    try {
        this.method = method;
        this.Url = new URL(ip+":"+port+url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.jsonObject = jsonObject;
    //Connect to URL
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) Url.openConnection();
        Log.i("Data", "Data sent => " + jsonObject.toString());

        try {
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(method);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json");
            httpURLConnection.connect();

            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());

            if(jsonObject != null)
            {
                outputStream.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString());
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            }


            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader((InputStream) httpURLConnection.getContent(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line = reader.readLine();

            while(line != null)
            {
                output.append(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        }finally {
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

String getMessge() {
    Log.i("Data", "Data received <= " + output.toString());
    return output.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: Freezing it's not happening on the async task. Because, asyntask operations is running background thread. Can you put your code here for the approximate solution for you?

Comment: To make http or https request without using AyncTask an alternative is to use Volley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) library.

You can find samples to use Retrofit easily.

https://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial

This is one of them.

Hope it to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for this.. I used this